# Include date type column in csv for oracle query result

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, xlsx

[Correction]

I am trying fetch query result in a xls using column headers in oracle

Below is the query

```
select
'Student Name'
'Joining Date'
from dual 
union all
select 
student_name
to_char(joining_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
from student_details
```

The only thing being that once I get this in a xlsfile , I am not able to sort the data using **joining_date** since it is converted to varchar/char.

I need a solution wherein I am able to include the headers and retain the data type (date,number) in the final xls result.(I can format cells in excel to date/number but I wish to get it done through database query itself)

Please help!

Comment: csv is just a text file with commas separating the data. There is nothing like datatype in it. Everything is a character. You should sort it in your query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Extract data as Oracle literals:

```
1) numbers - 123.354 

2) strings - q'{This is a string}' / 'This is another string'

3) dates - DATE'2016-04-31' 

4) dates with time/timestamps - TIMESTAMP'2016-04-31 11:13:00'/TIMESTAMP'2016-04-31 11:13:00.000000'
```